# Typescript: polymorhpic this, overload signature is not compatible with function implementation

Tags: typescript

Can someone explain why this doesn't work:

```
abstract class Model {
    static deserialize<T extends Model>(this: ( new() => T ), object: any): T;
    static deserialize<T extends Model>(ctor: ( new() => T ), object: any): T {
        return new ctor();
    }

    static deserializeArray<T extends Model>(this: ( new() => T ), ...objects: any[]): T[];
    static deserializeArray<T extends Model>(ctor: ( new() => T ), ...objects: any[]): T[] {
        return objects.map(object => Model.deserialize(ctor, object));
    }
}

class MyModel extends Model { }
```

Which would allow:

```
let myModel = MyModel.deserialize({});
let myModels = MyModel.deserializeArray({}, {}, {});
```

or

```
let myModel = Model.deserialize(MyModel, {});
let myModels = Model.deserializeArray(MyModel, {}, {}, {});
```

Typescript 2.5.2 complains that "Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation".

**Why are both forms needed?**

Consider a REST API that returns serialized (json) models:

```
class MyModelController {
    get(id: number) {
        let myModel = ... some db/service call ...
        return myModel.serialize();
    }
}
```

And then a generic service (angular) to request the model:

```
@Injectable()
abstract class HttpService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    errorHandler(response) {
        ...
    }

    get<T extends Model>(ModelType: ( new() => T ), endpoint: string): Observable<T> {
        return this.http.get(endpoint)
            // we can't call ModelType.deserialize() here...
            .map(response => Model.deserialize(ModelType, response.json()))
            .catch(response => this.errorHandler(response));
    }
}

@Injectable()
class MyModelService extends HttpService {
    get(id: number) {
       return super.get(MyModel, `/api/models/${id}`);
    }
}
```

**Solution**

```
abstract class Model {
    static deserialize<T extends Model>(this: ( new() => T), object: {}): T;
    static deserialize<T extends Model>(this: Function & { prototype: Model }, ctor: ( new() => T ), object: {});
    static deserialize<T extends Model>(this: ( new() => T), first: ( new() => T ) | {}, second?: any) {
        return typeof first === "function" ? new first() : new this(); 
    }

    static deserializeArray<T extends Model>(this: ( new() => T), ...objects: {}[]): T[];
    static deserializeArray<T extends Model>(this: Function & { prototype: Model }, ctor: ( new() => T ), ...objects: {}[]): T[];
    static deserializeArray<T extends Model>(this: ( new() => T), first: ( new() => T ) | {}[], second?: {}[]): T[] {
        const ctor = typeof first === "function" ? first : this;
        const objects = typeof first === "function" ? second : first;
        return objects.map(object => Model.deserialize(ctor, object));
    }
}
```

This allows both forms while preserving the `abstract`.

Comment: What's the point of the 2nd form? If you can do `MyModel.deserialize({});` why would you need to do `Model.deserialize(MyModel, {});`?

Comment: Yeah, but if you have the `ModelType` then you can simply do `ModelType. deserialize(...)`. It for sure extends `Model` and so it has a reference to the static `deserialize` function.

Comment: I am not able to call `ModelType.deserialize()`. If I refactor to include your `ModelCtor<T>` type (which has the deserialize signature), then `MyModel` is not assignable to `ModelCtor<T>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, there's no need to have both:

```
let myModel1 = MyModel.deserialize({});
let myModel2 = Model.deserialize(MyModel, {});
```

The first form is enough and more readable, and then the code will look like this:

```
type ModelCtor<T extends Model> = {
    new(): T;
    deserialize<T extends Model>(object: any): T;
    deserializeArray<T extends Model>(...objects: any[]): T[];
};

abstract class Model {
    static deserialize<T extends Model>(this: ModelCtor<T>, object: any): T {
        return new this();
    }

    static deserializeArray<T extends Model>(this: ModelCtor<T>, ...objects: any[]): T[] {
        return objects.map(object => this.deserialize(object));
    }
}

class MyModel extends Model { }

let myModel = MyModel.deserialize({});
let myModels = MyModel.deserializeArray({}, {}, {});
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ModelCtor%3CT%20extends%20Model%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20new()%3A%20T%3B%0A%20%20%20%20deserialize%3CT%20extends%20Model%3E(object%3A%20any)%3A%20T%3B%0A%20%20%20%20deserializeArray%3CT%20extends%20Model%3E(...objects%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20T%5B%5D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aabstract%20class%20Model%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20static%20deserialize%3CT%20extends%20Model%3E(this%3A%20ModelCtor%3CT%3E%2C%20object%3A%20any)%3A%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20this()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20static%20deserializeArray%3CT%20extends%20Model%3E(this%3A%20ModelCtor%3CT%3E%2C%20...objects%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20T%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20objects.map(object%20%3D%3E%20this.deserialize(object))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MyModel%20extends%20Model%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Alet%20myModel%20%3D%20MyModel.deserialize(%7B%7D)%3B%0Alet%20myModels%20%3D%20MyModel.deserializeArray(%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B))

However, if for some reason that is beyond me you do want to have both forms, then you can do something like:

```
type ModelCtor<T extends Model> = {
    new(): T;
    deserialize<T extends Model>(object: any): T;
    deserialize<T extends Model>(ctor: ModelCtor<T>, object: any): T;

    deserializeArray<T extends Model>(...objects: any[]): T[];
    deserializeArray<T extends Model>(ctor: ModelCtor<T>, ...objects: any[]): T[];
};

class Model {
    static deserialize<T extends Model>(this: ModelCtor<T>, object: any): T;
    static deserialize<T extends Model, S extends Model>(this: ModelCtor<T>, ctor: ModelCtor<S>, object: any): S;
    static deserialize<T extends Model, S extends Model>(this: ModelCtor<T>, first: ModelCtor<S> | any, second?: any): S {
        return second === undefined ? new this() : new first();
    }

    static deserializeArray<T extends Model>(this: ModelCtor<T>, ...objects: any[]): T[];
    static deserializeArray<T extends Model, S extends Model>(this: ModelCtor<T>, ctor: ModelCtor<S>, ...objects: any[]): S[];
    static deserializeArray<T extends Model, S extends Model>(this: ModelCtor<T>, ...objects: any[]): S[] {
        const ctor: ModelCtor<S> = typeof objects[0] === "function" ? objects[0] : this as any;
        return objects.map(object => ctor.deserialize(ctor, object));
    }
}

class MyModel extends Model { }

let myModel1 = MyModel.deserialize({});
let myModels1 = MyModel.deserializeArray({}, {}, {});

let myModel2 = Model.deserialize(MyModel, {});
let myModels2 = Model.deserializeArray(MyModel, {}, {}, {});
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20ModelCtor%3CT%20extends%20Model%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20new()%3A%20T%3B%0A%20%20%20%20deserialize%3CT%20extends%20Model%3E(object%3A%20any)%3A%20T%3B%0A%20%20%20%20deserialize%3CT%20extends%20Model%3E(ctor%3A%20ModelCtor%3CT%3E%2C%20object%3A%20any)%3A%20T%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20deserializeArray%3CT%20extends%20Model%3E(...objects%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20T%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20deserializeArray%3CT%20extends%20Model%3E(ctor%3A%20ModelCtor%3CT%3E%2C%20...objects%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20T%5B%5D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass%20Model%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20static%20deserialize%3CT%20extends%20Model%3E(this%3A%20ModelCtor%3CT%3E%2C%20object%3A%20any)%3A%20T%3B%0A%20%20%20%20static%20deserialize%3CT%20extends%20Model%2C%20S%20extends%20Model%3E(this%3A%20ModelCtor%3CT%3E%2C%20ctor%3A%20ModelCtor%3CS%3E%2C%20object%3A%20any)%3A%20S%3B%0A%20%20%20%20static%20deserialize%3CT%20extends%20Model%2C%20S%20extends%20Model%3E(this%3A%20ModelCtor%3CT%3E%2C%20first%3A%20ModelCtor%3CS%3E%20%7C%20any%2C%20second%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20S%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20second%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined%20%3F%20new%20this()%20%3A%20new%20first()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20static%20deserializeArray%3CT%20extends%20Model%3E(this%3A%20ModelCtor%3CT%3E%2C%20...objects%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20T%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20static%20deserializeArray%3CT%20extends%20Model%2C%20S%20extends%20Model%3E(this%3A%20ModelCtor%3CT%3E%2C%20ctor%3A%20ModelCtor%3CS%3E%2C%20...objects%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20S%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20static%20deserializeArray%3CT%20extends%20Model%2C%20S%20extends%20Model%3E(this%3A%20ModelCtor%3CT%3E%2C%20...objects%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20S%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20ctor%3A%20ModelCtor%3CS%3E%20%3D%20typeof%20objects%5B0%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22function%22%20%3F%20objects%5B0%5D%20%3A%20this%20as%20any%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20objects.map(object%20%3D%3E%20ctor.deserialize(ctor%2C%20object))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MyModel%20extends%20Model%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Alet%20myModel1%20%3D%20MyModel.deserialize(%7B%7D)%3B%0Alet%20myModels1%20%3D%20MyModel.deserializeArray(%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%0A%0Alet%20myModel2%20%3D%20Model.deserialize(MyModel%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%0Alet%20myModels2%20%3D%20Model.deserializeArray(MyModel%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B))

The code is more compilated (and I think that for no good reason).
Also, I had to remove the `abstract` part from `Model`, otherwise there's this error:

> The 'this' context of type 'typeof Model' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'ModelCtor'.
>   Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.

For both these lines:

```
let myModel2 = Model.deserialize(MyModel, {});
let myModels2 = Model.deserializeArray(MyModel, {}, {}, {});
```

Maybe you can play around with it a bit more and fix those errors without removing the `abstract`.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely pointed me in the right direction. I've updated the question to include a solution that preserves the `abstract`.